# Revolution Slider Not Showing

Tags: revolution-slider

I'm using revolution slider in my page. It is not showing first load page, but if I resize page or change tabs in browser, it is showing. How can I solve this problem?

http://ankarawebtasarim.com/rtasarim/

Solution I addet this js code:

```
revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
revapi1.revredraw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slider working fine for Chrome Browser. Over lapping jquery. deactivate sum plugins and checkit.

Comment: I solved my problem with this code:

revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
 revapi1.revredraw();
});